# Authentication error while pulling image from dockerhub private registry

Tags: kubernetes

When trying to run a pod that uses docker image from a private docker registry. I am getting the following error:

```
Warning  Failed     24s (x2 over 40s)  kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "registry.hub.docker.com/repository/docker/projecthelloworld/helloworld-container:V1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required
```

In order to find if there is any issue with the credentials, I tried to check the secret with the name `regcred` but I am not getting any output, which might be the reason why I am getting the authentication error.

```
k get secret regcred -o="jsonpath={.data .dockerconfigjson}"
```

This is how I created the secret `regcred` and the applied it:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry --dry-run=client regcred \
--docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ \
--docker-username=projecthelloworld \
--docker-password=HelloWorld240721 \
--docker-email=hello.world@gmail.com \
-o yaml > docker-secret.yaml
```

Here is the generated `docker-secret.yaml` is

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eyJodHRwczovL2luZGV4LmRvY2tlci5pby92MS8iOnsidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJwcm9qZWN0aGVsbG93b3JsZCIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiSGVsbG9Xb3JsZDI0MDcyMSIsImVtYWlsIjoiaGVsbG8ud29ybGRAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiYXV0aCI6ImNISnZhbVZqZEdobGJHeHZkMjl5YkdRNlNHVnNiRzlYYjNKc1pESTBNRGN5TVE9PSJ9fX0l
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: regcred
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Output of secret `k get secret regcred -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eyJodHRwczovL2luZGV4LmRvY2tlci5pby92MS8iOnsidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJwcm9qZWN0b3JjYSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiT3JjYTI0MDcyMSIsImVtYWlsIjoic3VyZXNoLnNoYXJtYUB0aGViaWdzY2FsZS5jb20iLCJhdXRoIjoiY0hKdmFtVmpkRzl5WTJFNlQzSmpZVEkwTURjeU1RPT0ifX19
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{".dockerconfigjson":"eyJhdXRocyI6eyJodHRwczovL2luZGV4LmRvY2tlci5pby92MS8iOnsidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJwcm9qZWN0b3JjYSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiT3JjYTI0MDcyMSIsImVtYWlsIjoic3VyZXNoLnNoYXJtYUB0aGViaWdzY2FsZS5jb20iLCJhdXRoIjoiY0hKdmFtVmpkRzl5WTJFNlQzSmpZVEkwTURjeU1RPT0ifX19"},"kind":"Secret","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":null,"name":"regcred","namespace":"default"},"type":"kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-21T03:18:14Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:.dockerconfigjson: {}
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
      f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-08-21T03:18:14Z"
  name: regcred
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "71712"
  uid: fa4b2b55-fe16-4921-9c65-7b5eddc820ba
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Then I created the following `hello-world-deploy.yml` deployment file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-deployment
  labels:
    app: hello-world-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-world-app
        image: registry.hub.docker.com/repository/docker/projecthelloworld/helloworld-container:V1
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80

      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

Following the above, I created deployment but the pod is showing the status `ErrImagePull`

On describing the pod, I can see that the secrets are mounted as expected.

```
Name:         hello-world-deployment-b74c8c7db-26r2f
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-192-168-41-226.eu-west-2.compute.internal/192.168.41.226
Start Time:   Tue, 03 Aug 2021 13:53:17 +0100
Labels:       app=hello-world-app
              pod-template-hash=b74c8c7db
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:       Pending
IP:           192.168.51.2
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.51.2
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/hello-world-deployment-b74c8c7db
Containers:
  hello-world-app:
    Container ID:
    Image:          registry.hub.docker.com/repository/docker/projecthelloworld/helloworld-container:hello-world-service.V.0
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        500m
      memory:     128Mi
    Environment:  <none>
Mounts:
  /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-h8j4t (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-h8j4t:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-h8j4t
    Optional:    false
```

I am not sure, in which step I am going wrong. Any help would greatly appreciated.

**Update**: I login to docker and tried to pull the image from command prompt

```
docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/repository/docker/projecthelloworld/helloworld-container:V1
```

and got the same response

```
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required
```

Output from the json.config file

```
{
        "auths": {
                "registry.hub.docker.com": {}
        },
        "credsStore": "desktop"
}
```

Comment: silly question have you done `kubectl create -f docker-secret.yaml` before pulling the image ?

Comment: Also, what does `k get secret regcred -o yaml` print. you may redact the private info

Comment: Hi, yes, I did, update the question with the yaml output

Comment: with the same credentials are you able to do `docker pull ...`

Comment: Hi P, I logged in to the docker with the same credentials, but I am getting the same error, I have updated the question.

Comment: Is this file present? ~/.docker/config.json

Comment: Hi P, yes, I am using mac, so I think its stored in credStore. Updated the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236254/discussion-between-tintin-and-p).

Comment: Occam's Razor would say your credentials are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, the deployment file's image property had a dns name `hub.docker.com` along with the uri path `/repository/docker/`

```
image: registry.hub.docker.com/repository/docker/projecthelloworld/helloworld-container:V1
```

Removing it got it working, it should have been

```
image: projecthelloworld/helloworld-container:V1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry dockersecret --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

This command worked for both Docker registry and DigitalOcean registry. Try removing the trailing "/" from --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/